# Parse stream gained from mjpg streamer to raw data in raspberry pi

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, live-streaming

I'm doing with raspberry pi and a usb camera, aiming to get live and continous raw data (instead of video or images) streaming from the usb camera. For example, keep saving the raw data in a file so I can see the raw data directly later.
What I have got now is the live video using the mjpg_streamer, by entering the ip address and port in a browser, I can see live video. I've tried a method online, which the code is like

```
import cv2
import urllib 
import numpy as np

stream = urllib.urlopen('http://localhost:8080')
bytes = ''
while True:
    bytes += stream.read(1024)
    a = bytes.find('\xff\xd8')
    b = bytes.find('\xff\xd9')
    if a != -1 and b != -1:
        jpg = bytes[a:b+2]
        bytes = bytes[b+2:]
        i = cv2.imdecode(np.fromstring(jpg, dtype=np.uint8), cv2.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR)
        cv2.imshow('i', i)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) == 27:
            exit(0)
```

where I tried keep the mjpg_streamer on, and then run this python code. However, this code seems not working for me. Simply I tried:

```
import cv2
import urllib.request
import numpy as np

stream = urllib.request.urlopen('http://localhost:8080/stream.html')
stream = stream.read(1024)
print(stream)
```

And I get result:

```
b'<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN"\n"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">\n<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">\n  <head>\n    <title>MJPG-streamer</title>\n    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />\n    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />\n    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>    \n    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.rotate.js"></script>\n    <!--[if IE 6]>\n    <link rel="stylesheet" href="fix.css" type="text/css" />\n    <![endif]-->\n    <script type="text/javascript">\n    \n    var phi = 0, flipped = 0, mirrored = 0;\n\n\tfunction setXformClass () {\n\t\t$(\'.xform\').each(function(idx,el) {\n\t\t\tel.className = "xform x" +(flipped ? "-flipped":"") + (mirrored ? "-mirrored" : "") + "-rotated-" + phi;\n\t\t});\n\t}\n    $(document).ready(function() {\n\t\t// set rotation angle phi and toggle rotate class\n\t\t$(\'#rotate\').click(function() {\n\t\t\tphi = (phi + 90) % 360;\n\t\t\tsetXformClass();\n\t\t\tif (phi % 180'
```

Based on the result, I didn't find the raw data that 'represent' the mjpg image data. Can someone please help me? Thank you in advance.

Comment: So, your camera delivers a web page that has options for other actions.  Have you opened that in a web page to see what it does?  It looks like the streaming is in `http://localhost:8080/stream.html`, but that's probably going to have a `<video>` tag to display the video.  Have you looked at the reference material for the USB camera to see if they have an RTSP URL to get the video stream directly?

Comment: Thank you sir. Just tried add on the 'stream.html' at the end of the address. And I put on the result as well. I'll try look up the RTSP URL now.

Comment: Again, you need to open these in a browser and examine the HTML.  Your update there got truncated, but it's clearly using a Javascript-based player of some kind.